# How to loop back from Z to A in nasm assembly language?

Tags: assembly, ascii, nasm

I have an assignment where I have to input a string and a number, and return string by adding that number to it. I have made a program, but after Z it returns awkward values, because of ascii, I guess. How to correct it?

This is my code-

```
section .text
global _start         

_start:                  
mov    ecx, len
mov    esi, bang        
mov    edi, tang

loop_here:
lodsb
add al, 02
stosb
loop    loop_here          
cld
rep     movsb

mov     edx,20        
mov     ecx,tang        
mov     ebx,1         
mov     eax,4       
int     0x80      

mov   edx,len2          
mov   ecx,newline   
mov   ebx,1         
mov   eax,4        
int   0x80          

mov     eax,1       
int     0x80     

section .data
bang db 'password' ;source
len equ $-bang
newline db 0xa
len2 equ $ - newline  

section .bss
tang resb 10
```

Comment: What's causing you problem? Thinking of the algorithm or implementing it?

Comment: Instead of `resb 10`, you could use `resb len+1` so it's always the same length as bang+newline.  Or just `len`, since it seems you're keeping the newline separate from your string?  Oh, so it doesn't get modified.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Let's assume that I change bang to "wxyz", then it will return "yz{|" , but I want it to return "yzab". How to do that?

Comment: If the result is > 'z', subtract 26 ('z'+1-'a').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> loop_here:
> lodsb
> add al, 02
> stosb
> loop    loop_here
> ```

When the addition produces a result that falls outside the range [a,z] (just above of **z**) then simply correct by subtracting 26.

```
loop_here:
 lodsb
 add   al, 02
 cmp   al, 'z'
 jbe   OK
 sub   al, 26
OK:
 stosb
 loop  loop_here
```

---

> ```
> loop    loop_here          
> cld
> rep     movsb
> ```

- There's no point in doing this `rep movsb` since ECX will be zero at this point right below the `loop`.
- You should better put the `cld` before the *loop_here* label.

---

> ```
> mov     edx,20        
> mov     ecx,tang        
> mov     ebx,1         
> mov     eax,4       
> int     0x80
> ```

If *tang* was defined to have **10** bytes, why then do you try to write **20** bytes?